# I want to setState before doing axios http request, but can't

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, asynchronous, axios

So, i want to change my props state before i send those to my backend through http request, but axios send those state before my if statement code execute. I don't understnad with this async thing. Here's the code

```js
login(){
    const url = 'https://myapi.execute-api.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/stage/resource';
    this.setState(()=>{
      if (this.state.email.indexOf('@') == -1){
        return {email: ''}
      } else {
        return {username: ''}
      }
    })
    axios.post(url, this.state).then(response => {
      if (response.data["message"])
        this.setState({message: response.data["message"]})
      else
        this.setState({message: response.data["token"]})
    })
  }
```

is someone has any solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it this way. First the state is set, then the axios request is being done. The `setState` function has as second parameter a callback.

Have a look also into the `react` documentation: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

```
login(){
    const url = 'https://myapi.execute-api.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/stage/resource';
    this.setState(()=>{
        if (this.state.email.indexOf('@') == -1){
            return {email: ''}
        } 
        else {
            return {username: ''}
        }
    },() => {
        axios.post(url, this.state).then(response => {
        if (response.data["message"])
            this.setState({message: response.data["message"]})
        else
            this.setState({message: response.data["token"]})
        })
    });
}
```

Comment: We now have [String.prototype.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) it is on Array.prototype as well so no more need to use `indexOf !== -1`

Comment: Yes, but remind that `includes` is particular not working in older browsers like IE11 out-of-the-box.